# How to unhide form on link click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, href

How can I show my html form when the edit link is clicked?

Anchor tag:

```
 <a href="#form?id=<?= $row["id"]; ?>" class="badge badge-success">edit</a>
```

Hidden html form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">+ Type Kamar</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $utk["id"]; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="gambarLamaa" value="<?= $utk["gambarr"]; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="room">Room</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="room" name="room" value="<?= $utk["room"]; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type">Type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" value="<?= $utk["type"]; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gambarr">picture</label>
            <br>
            <img src="../img/<?= $utk['gambarr']; ?>" width="700"> <br>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="gambarr" name="gambarr">
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="ubah" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP? Can't you just show/hide your form using Javascript / Jquery?

Comment: I've moved the question to the top of the page, and improved the wording of the question. The question which should have been asked is "how do I unhide this form on link click?"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not to use `aria-hidden="true"` to hide your content because if you hide it for now and when you need to again unhide it (setting its value to `aria-hidden="false"`) after clicking on the link it will misbehave inconsistently across browsers.(*According to MDN WebDocs*)

So instead use `display:none` to hide your form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" style="display:none">
```

Also set an id for the link

```
<a href="#form?id=<?= $row["id"]; ?>" id="link" class="badge badge-success">edit</a>
```

And you will need javascript to unhide it when clicked on the link as.

**JS**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('from').style.display = "block";
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your a href tag to:

```
<a href="#form?id=<?= $row["id"]; ?>" class="badge badge-success" onclick="show()">edit</a>
```

Then add a div around your form, id ="show-form", change the css of the div to:

```
#show-form {
display: none; }
```

and then add the following javascript:

```
     <script>function show() {
  var x = document.getElementById("show-form");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
} </script>
```